# How to update several vertices with same property in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I have a set of vertices which have the same property 'TYPE'. 
How to update this property for all the given set of vertices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can iterate through all your vertices and update their type property using a sideEffect. For example:

```
g.V.sideEffect{it.setProperty('TYPE',newTypeValue)}.iterate()
```

If you have a predefined set of vertices, you can do this:

```
mySetOfVertices._().sideEffect{it.setProperty('TYPE',newTypeValue)}.iterate()
```

Or...in pure Groovy:

```
mySetOfVertices.each{ it.setProperty('TYPE',newTypeValue) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Marko. Will post back if i find any problems.

Comment: Is there an advantage to the Gremlin form, or to the pure Groovy form?